# Count amount of specific values in list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

i am trying to count the 'a's in a given x list but this code is wrong and i cant figure out why

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'a']

def a_count(x):
    n = 0
    for ltr in x:
        if ltr == 'a':
            n = n + 1
        else :
            n = n
        return n
    return
```

i would also appreciate if someone could show me how to count the 'a's from another list that the user sets the values. this can be done by setting an empty  list like

```
y = []
```

and...then?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning too early, by changing the last few lines the function works fine

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'a']

def a_count(x):
    n = 0
    for ltr in x:
        if ltr == 'a':
            n = n + 1
    return n 

>>> a_count(x)
2
```

You can do this more succinctly like so:

```
>>> sum(elem == 'a' for elem in x)
2
```

The code above simply adds `0`s and `1s` (the reusults of `elem == 'a'` for reach element) to get the total number of `'a'`s

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'a']
>>> x.count('a')
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'a']

def a_count(x):
    n = 0
    for ltr in x:
        if ltr == 'a':
            n = n + 1
    return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that might come in handy:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ['a', 'b', 'a']
Counter(x)['a']
```

This will use a built in Collection counter to count all unique values.  Then accessing the count for `a`